# Paperclip routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

After I register a user, the request goes through and says that the registration was successful, but instead of the resized image appearing, the file name is the only thing that appears. Here is my error message:

```
Started GET "/system/photos/1/small/Picture%202.png?1312915420" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Aug 09    16:14:01 -0400 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/system/photos/1/small/Picture%202.png"):
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?  Explain it as if we know nothing about your app (because we don't)

Comment: Show us your view code and the controller code for user creation (the one with the upload attachment code)

Comment: I am having the same problem while using the storage as default. I am not able to create the different styles in the file system. I have describe the styles in has_attached_file in model. I am only able to see the original folder created after upload process is finished. No other styles like thumbnail, tiny etc are there. Showing the same error as conpill has written. I am using rails 3.0.7. I have also try writing the :url and :path tag but no success

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change this line in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false  #-> true
```